# php regex unlimited pattern

Tags: php, regex

I'm looking to extend the `regex` below so I can have unlimited number of braces.

```
((?:{[0-9]:[a-z]+})?)
```

So my string can handle `{1:foo}{2:bar}{3:more}`

Any ideas will be appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which function are you using in PHP for matching the expression? Using [preg_match_all](http://php.net/preg_match_all) should work for you with the follow regex: `/\{([0-9]):([a-z]+)\}/`